# UWP app in multiple languages - Check all languages

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-store

I'm developing a universal app for Windows 10 (UWP), and my application is available in several languages. I already have the application ready, and now I'm preparing the submission in the Windows Store. Is there any way I can see my application in each of the languages without changing the language and region of my Windows 10 computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the Settings app you can add a language and make it the default without switching the full UI or downloading a language pack.

Go to `Time & Language` then `Region & Language`, add a language from there, and make it the default. You can switch back to your preferred language using the same UI.

You can see detailed instructions in Step 1.3 of [this whitepaper](http://aka.ms/mrtforcentennial) -- don't worry that it's about the Desktop Bridge.